# Move-ADObject : The operation could not be performed because the object's parent is either uninstantiated or deleted

Tags: windows, powershell

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-ADComputer NAME | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=SERVERS,OU=COUNTY,
OU=STATE,OU=REGION,OU=COUNTRY,DC=subdomain,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
```

However, I am getting this:

> Move-ADObject : The operation could not be performed because the
>   object's parent is either uninstantiated or deleted

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Is ADComputer not piping over correctly? Examples show this is valid.

I am trying to move the computer to a new OU out of the default.

Comment: Is the `=` before the quoted OU in `-TargetPath` a typo in just the question? Or did you put that on the command line as well?

Comment: Ah, the = would be a typo. Opps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get this error message is to have a spelling error somewhere in the DN for the OU path.  A possible test for this is to use something like

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -lDAPFilter "(name=SERVERS)"
```

Look at the DistinguishedName property and see if there is any difference.  You can also capture the resulting object and pass the DistinguishedName property to the Move-ADObject -TargetPath parameter.  Something like:

```
$newServer = Get-ADComputer 'ServerName'
$targetOU = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -lDAPFilter "(name=SERVERS)"
Move-ADObject -Identity $newServer -TargetPath $targetOU.DistinguishedName
```

Answer (score 0):

This message is repeatable if your "-TargetPath" is incorrect, make the system give it to you.

$OU = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter  "name -like '*[OUName]*'").DistinguishedName
Get-ADComputer [ComputerName] | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $OU